# Trust Region Radius Initialization for Matlab 'fmincon'

Tags: matlab, optimization

When I use the Matlab, I'm trying to use 'fmincon' to implement 'Trust Region' Optimization, and I cannot find the way to initialize the radius.

I tried using 'InitTrustRegionRadius' in 'options', but looks like didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.